Can't Update paginated report data source of as semantic model using rest api
I've created a paginated report by power bi report builder. Used power bi semantic model as data source then published it on power bi service. After that I cloned report by REST API.
Now I want to change the data source as another semantic model of cloned report. I also tried by this endpoint
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportId}/Default.UpdateDatasources

Payload:
{
  "updateDetails": [
    {
      "datasourceName": "<dataSourceName>",
      "connectionDetails": {
        "workspaceId": "<workspaceId>",
        "datasetId": "<datasetId>"
      }
    }
  ]
}

The request return success but actually the report doesn't show data from updated semantic model.
I read the Reports - Update Datasources documentation to update paginated repot's data source  but there no example to upate semantic model as data source
I'm looking for an approach to update the data source as semantic model.
